# Click fadeToggle in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with fadeToggle() in jQuery when clicking on an element .. for example this code :

HTML :

```
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="submenu">this is submenu</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$('.element').click(function(){


    $('.submenu').fadeToggle();

});
```

The problem is when i click on $('.element') multiple times the element blinks multiple times after clicking .. so what to do to fix that ?

Try to click multiple times : https://jsfiddle.net/ty6s2ymL/

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dtt8680x/ ? The click handler "waits" x milliseconds before actually doing the work. If there is another click in-between the x milliseconds the timer resets and the waiting begins from the start

Comment: Thank you for the answer .. i didn't know that something like this exists .. but it's a wonderful idea .. but in my case .stop() solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.stop()`

```
$(".submenu").stop(true, true).fadeToggle();
```

The `.stop()` parameters are: `clearQueue`, `jumpToEnd`

This will almost immediately stop the current animation. To have a more 'smooth' stopping, you should call `.stop(true, false)`

Reference: [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)